# Calculation of an expression ($\max_{U}\min_i \sum_j |U_{ij}|^2 |e_i^j|^2$)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, summation

There is an orthonormal basis $\{e_i\}(i=1,\ldots,n)$ in $\mathbb{C}^n$, each of them is represented in form of column vectors $$\begin{pmatrix} e_i^1\\ \vdots\\e_i^n\end{pmatrix}.$$

My purpose is to calculate the following expression:
$$
\max_{U}\min_i \sum_j |U_{ij}|^2 |e_i^j|^2,
$$
where $U$ is any $n$-dimension unitary matrix.

Comment: The optimisation problem can be reformulated as maximising the minimum diagonal element of $PQ$, where $P=(|U_{ij}|^2)$ (arbitrary) and $Q=(|e_i^j|^2)$ (given) are orthostochastic matrices. Note that $P$ and $Q$ are doubly stochastic. Now consider the relaxed problem to maximise the minimum diagonal element of $PQ$ over all doubly stochastic $P$. By Birkhoff's theorem, we can write $P$ as a convex combination of permutation matrices. So we end up with an optimisation problem that is not convex. In view of this, I don't think the original problem has any closed-form solution.